# How to support several Android projects with a slight difference in the code effectively?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

We initially had only one project (let's call it `Project A`), but over time it became necessary to make the same application with client branding (`Project B`). The only difference from the original project were colors, the drawable and the code in some classes.

I decided to make a copy of the branch in Git and implement changes for the `Project B`. As a result, now I have 2 applications with code duplication is about 95%. The main problem is that to make changes in the code for the same application time is very costly since these two branches can not be merged. They have a different package, and the package name on the Android matches the path to the files on the disk. Accordingly, all the files are simply in different directories.

I drew attention to the [Product Flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors). This solves the question of "how to support 2 projects in one git branch", but it is not clear how to effectively make changes to the common code for the files with a small difference (some lines in each class).

**How should I make a change only once in this case? Perhaps, you have encountered such a problem before.**

Comment: You could please accept the answer or at least comment it.

Answer (score 0):

You already answered the first question, which is using Product Flavors. For the second question you will also be using those product flavors, and the answer is to simply create a base, `abstract` class, and have two, concrete classes *with the same name* extending from the base one, each one residing on their own flavor.

I'll give you an example:

```
package com.application.main;
public abstract class BaseMainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDifferingMethod();
    }

    public abstract void myDifferingMethod();

}
```

And then, you create concrete classes which override the method:

Flavor A:

```
package com.application.main;
public class MainActivity extends BaseMainActivity {
    @Override
    public void myDifferingMethod() {
        System.out.println("im on A product flavor");
        doStuff();
    }
```

and flavor B:

```
package com.application.main;
public class MainActivity extends BaseMainActivity {
    @Override
    public void myDifferingMethod() {
        System.out.println("im on B product flavor");
        // don't do nothing
    }
```